# How to wait for a while and then suspend current work on open new terminal in a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, scripts

I have a program called `mdr-dev` that I execute and that as a result opens port 1022.

After opening that port, I have to leave the program running to keep that port open.  *The snag is that it takes some time to execute so in the mean time I should wait for it to open that port!*

Once the port is open, I want to open a new terminal and `ssh` through that port to a remote device.

*The question is: How to write a bash or any other script for this?*

(I already tried with the sleep command but it does not seem to work.)

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $MDR_ROOT
mdr-dev --root --mount /opt/tile/home /home --tunnel 1022 22
```

After the `mdr-dev` command above's initialisation process, I want to automatically open a new terminal and run:

```
ssh -p 1022 root@localhost
```

Off course, I already tried:

```
--tunnel 1022 22 &
sleep 5m 
xterm -hold -e ssh -p 1022 root@localhost
```

but that doesn't seem to work...

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: I don't quite get what you are trying to do. You want to run `mdr-dev` command and upon its completion open new terminal window with `ssh ` ?  Why you cannot just add `xterm` command at the end of the script ? Also, command for xterm should be `xterm -hold -e 'ssh -p 1022 root@localhost'`

Comment: What does `mdr-dev` actually do?  How do you know it's finished?

Comment: @Serg `mdr-dev` after completion goes into interactive mode. I can suspend only after its complete initialization and it takes some time. So I wait till its initialization is done and then open a new terminal and run `ssh -p 1022 root@localhost` in the new terminal

Comment: @Fabby mdr-dev initializes the device connected to the linux machine. It runs in an interactive mode. `--root` is one the options fed to it. It must be kept running after the initialization so I want to keep it running and open new terminal to do `ssh`

Comment: So that's when you use `&`: `mdr-dev` keeps on running and that allows you to `ssh` in parallel...  It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish here.  Why don't you want `&`?

Comment: @Fabby if I do `mdr-dev --root --mount /opt/tile/home /home --tunnel 1022 22 &` and then `xterm -hold -e ssh -p 1022 root@localhost` it will fail because `mdr-dev` need some time to initialize localport and in the mean time I should not do anything. Once port is set up then i am allowed to do `ssh`

Comment: **Andi99:** I've edited your question to better reflect what you're after...  Please [edit] it and review what I've understood so far and change whatever I've misunderstood!  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby that looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't have your `mdr-dev` program, it's difficult for me to test this, so here goes version 0.1.  Please test and feed back in the comments.

```
#!/bin/bash  
#
# This script opens a port to tunnel through, then waits for the tunnel to be opened
# and then connects to the correct host using ssh  
# Answer to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/682316/how-to-wait-for-a-while-and-then-suspend-current-work-on-open-new-terminal-in-a

# Copyright (c) Fabby 2015

# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.
# You DID NOT receive a copy of the GNU General Public License along with this program as the license is bigger then this program.
# Therefore, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/ for more details.

# version 0.1   dd 2015-10-08   First version.

### Init ###
declare -r bDebug=false
declare szPortOpen=""
if $bDebug ; then
  set -x
  declare iDebugTimeOut=30 #seconds
fi

### Main ###
echo "$MDR_ROOT"
# open tunnel:
mdr-dev --root --mount /opt/tile/home /home --tunnel 1022 22 &

if $bDebug ; then
  read -t $iDebugTimeOut -p "Hit [Enter] to continue..."
fi

#Wait for the tunnel to open
while [ -z "$szPortOpen" ]
do
  sleep 1m
  netstat -atn | grep ":1022" | (read szPortOpen; )
  if $bDebug ; then
    echo $szPortOpen
    read -t $iDebugTimeOut -p "Hit [Enter] to continue..."
  fi
done

# Now ssh to the server 
xterm -hold -e ssh -p 1022 root@localhost
```

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: thank you. System got stuck is what happened. So used some print statements. after `mdr-dev --root --mount /opt/tile/home /home --tunnel 1022 22 &` `echo "end main"` inside `if $bDebug` loop `echo "inside loop"`  inside while loop after `sleep 1m`  `echo "sleep ended" and just before `ssh` command I wrote `doing ssh`. Here is the log of these print statements, end main, _italic_ sleep ended  sleep ended sleep ended _italic_  ......So I think it never came out of while loop.

Comment: Can you post your version to http://paste.ubuntu.com?  Because mine does contain debug statements... Did you turn on debug?

Comment: here is a little modification to your code just to understand your code flow. http://paste.ubuntu.com/12729567/

Comment: Reading tomorrow as I'm falling over from exhaustion.  Sorry about this.

Comment: You're a reputation 1 user so we cannot take this up in chat.  Can you provide the output?